# How do I override DefaultErrorHandler in a Log4j 2 Socket appender?

Tags: tomcat, log4j, tomcat7, log4j2

Currently my `<Socket>` appender defined in XML uses `org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.DefaultErrorHandler` but it prints some information that I don't want to appear in `catalina.out`.

### log4j2.xml

Here is what I currently have:

```
<Appenders>
    <Socket name="socketLoggerAdapter" host="my-server" port="4006" protocol="UDP" reconnectionDelayMillis="60000">
        <JsonLayout properties="true"/>
    </Socket>
...
<Appenders>
```

I was hoping that I could add a child element `<handler class="com.mycompany.MyErrorHandler">` but I couldn't find anything addressing this use case in the Log4j 2 documentation.

Could someone point me to some documentation or give basic steps on how I can implement this?

### What I want to suppress

My `catalina.out` logs this occasionally during tomcat startup and I don't want it to be reported:

```
2020-06-30 18:12:38,238 AsyncAppender-myAppenderRef-socketAppender ERROR An exception occurred processing Appender socketAppender org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AppenderLoggingException: Error flushing stream UDP:myserver:9006
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.OutputStreamManager.flush(OutputStreamManager.java:176)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AbstractOutputStreamAppender.append(AbstractOutputStreamAppender.java:107)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.tryCallAppender(AppenderControl.java:165)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppender0(AppenderControl.java:138)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppenderPreventRecursion(AppenderControl.java:129)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppender(AppenderControl.java:97)
    at com.mycompany.MyCustomAppender$AsyncThread.callAppender(MyCustomAppender.java:455)
    at com.mycompany.MyCustomAppender$AsyncThread.run(MyCustomAppender.java:398)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Message too long
    ... 8 more
```

### Other info

Here is how an error handler is initialized:

```
org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.DefaultErrorHandler.<init>(org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Appender) line: 47  
org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.ConsoleAppender(org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AbstractAppender).<init>(java.lang.String, org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Filter, org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Layout<? extends java.io.Serializable>, boolean) line: 40  
org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.ConsoleAppender(org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AbstractOutputStreamAppender<M>).<init>(java.lang.String, org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Layout<? extends java.io.Serializable>, org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Filter, boolean, boolean, M) line: 60   
org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.ConsoleAppender.<init>(java.lang.String, org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Layout<? extends java.io.Serializable>, org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Filter, org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.OutputStreamManager, boolean) line: 69   
org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.ConsoleAppender.createDefaultAppenderForLayout(org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Layout<? extends java.io.Serializable>) line: 106   
org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.DefaultConfiguration.<init>() line: 62 
org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.<init>(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object, java.net.URI) line: 75   
org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.locateContext(java.lang.ClassLoader, java.net.URI) line: 145  
org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.getContext(java.lang.String, java.lang.ClassLoader, boolean, java.net.URI) line: 70   
org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.getContext(java.lang.String, java.lang.ClassLoader, boolean) line: 57 
org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(java.lang.String, java.lang.ClassLoader, java.lang.Object, boolean) line: 141 
org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(java.lang.String, java.lang.ClassLoader, java.lang.Object, boolean) line: 41  
org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(java.lang.ClassLoader, boolean) line: 185    
org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory(org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLoggerAdapter<L>).getContext(java.lang.Class<?>) line: 103 
org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getContext() line: 43   
org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory(org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLoggerAdapter<L>).getLogger(java.lang.String) line: 42 
org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(java.lang.String) line: 29    
org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(java.lang.String) line: 358   
org.apache.log4j.Logger(org.apache.log4j.Category).<init>(java.lang.String) line: 57    
org.apache.log4j.Logger.<init>(java.lang.String) line: 37   
org.apache.log4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(java.lang.String) line: 43    
org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(java.lang.String) line: 41    
org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(java.lang.Class) line: 49 
com.mycompany.core.security.SessionUtil.<clinit>() line: 24 
com.mycompany.MyCompanyContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent) line: 14 
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart() line: 4812 
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal() line: 5255 
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext(org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase).start() line: 150  
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost(org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase).addChildInternal(org.apache.catalina.Container) line: 725 
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost(org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase).addChild(org.apache.catalina.Container) line: 701 
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(org.apache.catalina.Container) line: 717 
org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(org.apache.catalina.util.ContextName, java.io.File) line: 945  
org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run() line: 1795   
java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter<T>.call() line: 471  
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask<V>.run() line: 262  
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker) line: 1145    
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run() line: 615  
java.lang.Thread.run() line: 745
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there was another recent Stackoverflow question regarding this. This was an oversight on my part and you should create a Jira issue for this. While you can call the setErrorHandler method to change the ErrorHandler there is no way to configure one because it is not initialized as a plugin.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Just one question before I submit an issue: should the error handler be for my socket appender, or for the console appender that writes to catalina.out? Can catalina.out's appender even be customized?

Comment: The error handler could be applied to any Appender, including the ConsoleAppender.

Comment: Right, but will I be able to stop this stack trace appearing in catalina.out? I just want to be sure I request the right thing.

Comment: Also, I see Bugzilla but no Jira. http://tomcat.apache.org/bugreport.html

Comment: If you provide your own error handler you should be able to modify how the error message is logged. You shouldn't be looking at Tomcat's error reporting process to report an issue in Log4j. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/LOG4J2.